# Fill in matrix from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matrix

Using the following df:

```
|Research|Thesis|Proposal|AI|Analytics|Data|
| -------|------|-------_|--|---------|----|
| 54     | 0    |0       |0 |5        |  0 |
| 33     | 43   |5       |0 |0        |  81|
```

I need to create 2*2 matrices for all possible pairs of columns,

```
eg: (0,1), (0,2), ... (0,n)
(1,2), (1,3),  (1,n)                 
(2,3), (2,4), (2,5), .....(2,n)
```

populate it with values in those columns

For the pair(0,1) the matrix should be composed of the words in columns 0 and 1 for school 1 and the words in columns 0 and 1 for school 2

eg: For the pair [Research,Thesis] or (0,1), the matrix would be

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 54 | 0 |
| 33 | 43 |

For the pair [Research,Thesis] or (0,2), the matrix would be

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 54 | 0 |
| 33 | 5 |

and make sure that every row and column sums to a value > zero (if they do not, not include them)i.e. for a 2*2 matrix m, we can check the first row:
if (m[0,0] + m[0,1]) > 0. Need to do that for the second row as well as the first and second columns

I have used 2 for loops to get all possible pairs but I am unable to create my matrices and check if every row and column sums to >0 for all combinations.

```
data=[[54, 0, 0, 6, 5, 0,],[33, 43, 5, 0, 76, 81]]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['Research', 'Thesis', 'Proposal', 
'AI', 'Analytics', 'Data'])
#The 2 loops below create all possible pairs
for i in range(0,len(df.columns)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(df.columns)):
            matrix = np.zeros((2,2))
```

Any help will be immensely appreciated!

**EDIT**
The output should just be a collection of matrices

Comment: kindly post the expected output dataframe

Comment: just a collection of matrices, no df

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, one way using `itertools.combinations` with operators:

```
from itertools import combinations

matrices = [d for c1, c2 in combinations(df.columns, 2) 
            if (d:=df[[c1, c2]]).sum(1).gt(0).all()]
```

Output:

```
# len(matrices)
[   Research  Thesis
0        54       0
1        33      43,
    Research  Proposal
0        54         0
1        33         5,
    Research  AI
0        54   6
1        33   0,
    Research  Analytics
0        54          5
1        33         76,
    Research  Data
0        54     0
1        33    81,
    Thesis  AI
0       0   6
1      43   0,
    Thesis  Analytics
0       0          5
1      43         76,
    Proposal  AI
0         0   6
1         5   0,
    Proposal  Analytics
0         0          5
1         5         76,
    AI  Analytics
0   6          5
1   0         76,
    AI  Data
0   6     0
1   0    81,
    Analytics  Data
0          5     0
1         76    81]
```